# Generate multi level customer receipt for order

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

My target is to generate a view for customer receipt which they will get after they submit an order. The receipt should contain all  the food items they order. Each food item can contain multiple sub items.

Model is returning data like below;

[image]

if you see carefully, those who have parentitemid are sub items. and they should be shown under their parent item.

The target should look like as below;

[image]

Now the problem is i have tried many things (i.e. if-else inside the foreach and etc)
but did not get this view.

Will it be possible to generate such view from this kind of data ??
Can anyone help me out with some idea plzzz !

**EDIT:**

I have some progress..here how it looks now..
[image]

Now, how would i show the price of sub item under the main item...??

here is my code

```
<%foreach (var i in Model.OrderItems)
      { %>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;">1</td>
        <td style="width:40%;"><%:i.fiitemName%>
        <br />
        <table style="margin-left:10px;">
            <%foreach (var k in Model.getOrderSubItems("36-171012-2", i.fiID))
              { %>

                    <tr style="height:30px;">
                        <td style="width:100px;"><%:k.FoodItemName %></td>
                        <td style="width:100px;"><%:k.SubItemPrice %></td>
                    </tr>
           <%} %>
           </table>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;"><%:i.msize%></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;"><%:i.ItemNote %></td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;"><%:i.mprice%></td>

      </tr>

    <%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

How does your model look ? A simple model example:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public List<Item> SubItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then to display you can loop through all items on an order and then in that item loop any sub items.

```
foreach (var item in Order.Items)
        {
            foreach (var subItems in item.SubItems)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi..yes my model looks similar..But i think what i am struggling with some HTML. I have posted some more code and the problem.

Comment: What is k.SubItemPrice? That looks like the price of the sub item? Is this not displaying ?